# Why does A-sI have a better condition number than A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let A be a $n\times n$ matrix, $s$ be real number and $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Why does $A$ have a worse condition number than $A-sI$?

I suspect it is something to do with the singular values being closer together for the matrix $A-sI$ than for $A$. I was wondering how I could mathematically prove this was the case. My linear algebra is a bit rusty. References would also be amazing.

Edit:

Some code to illustrate observations

Edit:

previous code example had bugs

Comment: See [this blog](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2017/07/17/what-is-the-condition-number-of-a-matrix/).

Comment: This doesn’t sound right. E.g. consider $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$. Then $A$ is nonsingular (and hence it has a finite condition number) but $A-I$ is nonzero and singular (and its condition number is infinite).

Comment: @HHH This statement is not generally true. Why do you believe that this is the case? Is there a specific problem you were thinking about when you encountered this supposed phenomenon?

Comment: @HHH To say a bit more about user1551's example, the condition number of $A - sI$ (for that particular matrix) is minimized only when $s = 0$. In other words, for any $s \neq 0$, $A - sI$ has a worse condition number than $A$.

Comment: Take any positive definite $A$ not multiple of identity. Then $A-sI$ will have strictly worse condition number than $A$ as long as $0<s<\sigma_{min}(A)$

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of $A+sI$, $s>0$ for $A$ spd? This is known is Tikhonov regularization and does improve the 2-condition number as $s$ is increased

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comments! @BenGrossmann I would be interested in seeing a proof for this? Do you have a reference? The reason for the question is that I have empirically observed better conditioning when approximating a matrix A as a super position of a diagonal matrix plus the product of two low rank matrices + shifted inverse

Comment: @HHHH Just calculate the eigenvalues of $A-sI$ directly; you get $\pm 1-s$. For a symmetric matrix, the singular values are the absolute values of the eigenvalues. The condition number is the ratio between the two singular values. The only $s$ for which the eigenvalues have the same absolute value is $s=0$.

Comment: @HHHH Can you say more about how you’re generating this approximation? I recommend editing that into your question.

Comment: @HHHHH Since this is an empirical observation, perhaps you could give us a typical example

Comment: @HHHHH Some observations from your code: note that all the matrices involved have positive entries. Also, instead of subtracting a multiple of the identity, you seem to be subtracting a row of ones from each row of $B$. Why did you make s a vector rather than a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity matrix is an optimally conditioned matrix: $κ()=1$. Moreover, condition numbers are independent of rescaling: $κ(λA)=κ(A)$ for $λ≠0$.

What $A-s$ does is it biases $A$ towards an identity matrix. We have $κ(A-s) = κ(-\tfrac{1}{s}A) → κ()=1$  as $|s|→∞$.

Therefore, for large enough values of $s$ it is essentially guaranteed that the condition number improves. The only case when this is not necessarily true is when you start with an already optimally conditioned matrix, such as $\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$. But even in this case, you'd only increase the condition number by some small $ε>0$ for large $s$.

As noted in the comments, for too small values of $s$ the condition number can increase significantly.